# Draw Overlay in Android (system wide)

Tags: android, linux, overlay, framebuffer

Is there a way to draw an overlay window always on top of any android application?

I am using Android x86 port and have system rights.

@Edit: The view below the overlay should receive all events.

Comment: AFAIK there is no legit way to do it within the SDK. However some apps on the market have managed to accomplish it. 

If you do find a way I wouldn't count on it working forever, they chose not to include a public API for this for valid security reasons.

Comment: Is not intended for the Android market. I want to modify Android itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to do that by creating a `Service` that adds the view in the current `WindowManager`:

```
public class OverlayService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        View overlay = /* create your overlay here */;

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        windowManager.addView(overlay , params);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

But you need this extra permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

And then just register the service in the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".OverlayService" ></service>
```

and start it:

```
startService(new Intent(this, OverlayService.class));
```

Comment: Will this solution path-through all events to the views below the overlay? I have forgotten to add this to the question.

Comment: you just need to add the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` flag

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [library](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark) just removing this method [addWatermarkWithinApplicationLifecycle()](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark/blob/5e5ea23e17829c8130a7cf2396608b52b2b2fd41/App-Watermark/src/main/java/com/gk/emon/app/watermark/AppWaterMarkBuilder.kt#L205) which sticks the overlay with the app lifecycle (*As you want to show the overlay all over the phone app*). Please also don't forget to add these permissions -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION"/>
```

The gif preview of my library -

[image]