# capture movements or keystrokes of a game like (Angry Bird) using touch screen of an Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I basically need to find out if there is a way to capture movements or keystrokes of a game such as "Angry Birds" etc using the touch screen of an Android and save them to a file on the device.

I'm sure these phones have security issues and don't want native "keystroke logging", but if it's a layer that sits over the other game, it should be ok

Please let me is there any way to achieve the same. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can cover the screen using a System Overlay, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13346388/1069068).

However, keep in mind that either you can consume all the touch events, or you can let them through. You cannot first take the touch events, and then pass them onto the app or View below you.

Additionally, if the device has on screen system navigation buttons (home, back and recent apps) the overlay will not cover these.