# how to protect the notification bar?

Tags: android, statusbar, motionevent

I want to detect the action based on the status bar. In fact I want to limit the right of this section. i tried

```
mGrid.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
               public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1){
                    int x = (int) arg1.getX();
                    int y = (int) arg1.getY();
                    Log.d("Screen", String.valueOf(x));
                    Log.d("Screen", String.valueOf(y));
                    switch(arg1.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                        Log.d("tototootot", "acces dinied");
                    //case MotionEvent.


                    }


                    return true;
               }
```

Comment: Status bar as in notification bar?

Comment: You can't. The notification bar is outside your app area. Motion events on it will not be passed to you

Comment: so how can i detect an action in this bar?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  It's  much easier to hide the notification bar entirely if it's just taking up real estate on the screen that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really detect touches and events on the notification bar.

You can however block all touches from reaching it entirely by drawing over the notification bar with a system overlay that doesn't let touch events filter through. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13346111/1069068) SO question shows how to draw an overlay. Make sure to remove it once you are done with your app, as it will persist regardless of which app is in the foreground.