# Android: system overlay

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to Overlay screen?

1. it should be touchable
2. view must overlay system action bar
3. view must overlay soft buttons back/home/recent_apps
4. Android 4.0 +

   ```
   public class MyService extends Service {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       WindowManager.LayoutParams params = ViewUtils.generateFullScreenParams(true);

       final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
       wm.addView(overlayView, params);
   }
   ...
   }
   ```

and layout params creator

```
public static WindowManager.LayoutParams generateFullScreenParams() {
    return new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,

            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,

            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
}
```

ok, looks good.

Flag TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT **not** overlays the system bar (android < 5.0), **not** overlays soft buttons, but **I can** to handle onTouch event

Flag TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY **overlays** the system bars, **not overlays** buttons and I **can't** to handle onTouch event.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you net setting theme FullScreen with no titlebar?

Comment: this view attached from service, but theme actual for an activities. Сorrect me if I'm wrong

Comment: You creating View inside Service inside OnCreate ?? like dialog?

Comment: maybe I can to detect touch on screen event without view? (for all applications)

Comment: No you can not do that. Again what you can do is use system alert below M and take users concern from pendingintent notification with addaction buttons and the run your service instead of opening an activity for performing the task related to users input in background

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw Overlay in Android (system wide)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346111/draw-overlay-in-android-system-wide)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static WindowManager.LayoutParams generateFullScreenParams() {
    return new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,

            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,

            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
}
```

in This Code You added `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`
remove this line its works and add touch event on view its works

For The Screen Overlay permission I am Referring to this post [How to enable screen overlay permission by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337131/how-to-enable-screen-overlay-permission-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [library](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark) just removing this method [addWatermarkWithinApplicationLifecycle()](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark/blob/5e5ea23e17829c8130a7cf2396608b52b2b2fd41/App-Watermark/src/main/java/com/gk/emon/app/watermark/AppWaterMarkBuilder.kt#L205) which sticks the overlay with the app lifecycle (*As you want to show the overlay all over the phone app*).I tried to do it in a reusable way that you can hide and show overlay just a simple method call.  Please also don't forget to add these permissions -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION"/>
```

The gif preview of my library -

[image]