# error Launch AlertDialog.Builder from Service

Tags: android

hello everybody I'm trying to launch CountDownTimer dialog from Service when push notification receive . i want wake up screen  and use system alert dialog ; 
 I use  permissions :

> "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW", "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"

but when get notification, get below error and service carash :

```
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)

                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:46)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:97)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:929)
                                                                       at com.iransnaptaxi.taxi.Server.PusheServic.ShowDialog(PusheServic.java:91)
                                                                       at com.iransnaptaxi.taxi.Server.PusheServic.onMessageReceived(PusheServic.java:48)

                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:297)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

and I tried to luanch it with  below cod:

```
private void ShowDialog(){

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK| PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "taxiWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();



    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), R.style.AppTheme_MaterialDialogTheme);

     dialogBuilder.setTitle("درخواست سفر")
            .setMessage("درخواست سفر دارید").setNegativeButton("لغو", null)
            .setPositiveButton("مشاهد سفر", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                }
            });

    final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    final Window dialogWindow = dialog.getWindow();
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams dialogWindowAttributes = dialogWindow.getAttributes();


    dialogWindow.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    dialogWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    dialogWindowAttributes.windowAnimations = R.anim.dialogue_scale_anim_open;
    dialog.show();
    new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            dialog.setMessage("زمان مانده تا لغو درخواست"+"00:"+ (millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }.start();



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to show dialog from `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask`. Show it from the `onPostExecute()` method. UI elements can only be used from the UI thread not from the background thread.

Try this if you get Looper error:

```
Looper.prepare();
showDialog();
Looper.loop();
```

Also you need `Activity` context to create AlertDialogs. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22627480/5137352) to create dialogs from inside the service.

Comment: i call this method from  class that extend service  created by pushe library 
and u can see  methods of class [here](https://imgur.com/kiqoRQW)

Comment: Your stacktrace indicates that the method is being called from an AsyncTask. Try calling adding `Looper.prepare();` before showDialog(); and `Looper.loop();` after it.

Comment: thank you very much ,'Looper' work for me pleas edit your main answer to help other have same problem ,

Comment: Hello again , This works great on Android 5, but does not work on Android 6 and above, although the TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY access permission is enabled in the settings. can you help me ?

Comment: check this question and it's answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337131/how-to-enable-screen-overlay-permission-by-default